# What is the intuitive reason that partial differential equations are hard to solve?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

My question is why it is difficult to find analytical solutions for these equations.

Is there any intuition why numerical solutions are preferred?

Comment: Much like with ODEs, the ones we care about from a research perspective generally don't have an analytic solution. Also, PDEs are highly dependent on the shape of the region over which you're solving them, which adds a layer of complexity over what we know about differential equations.

Comment: It's not news when some problems are hard to solve; it is news when a problem is easy to solve.

Answer (score 2):

For differential equations in general I think there doesn't seem to exist a "method " for finding the solutions, unlike taking a derivative,  for instance,  which involves evaluating a certain limit, namely  $lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f (x+h)-f (x)}h $...

Answer (score 2):

Do not think that ODEs and PDEs are of different natures. An ODE is a kind of PDE wrt only one variable, while a PDE is wrt several variables.

It is not surprising that solving equations with more variables is more difficult than equations with less variables. I think that is the simplest intuitive reason which answers to your question.

Especially if one considers the boundary conditions in cases of ODE ("one variable PDE") and PDEs with more and more variables.

Finding the general solution is one thing. But finding, among all solutions, the particular one which fits the boundary conditions is generaly an even more difficult task.

In case of "one variable PDE", the boundary conditions are given on a limited number of points (number related to the order of the equation).

In case of "two variables PDE", the boundary conditions are given on a limited number of curves. In case of "three variables PDE", the boundary conditions are given on a limited number of surfaces. And so on.

One understand that the fitting task is harder in case of curve than in case of point, an even more arduous on surface. And so on.